# searching Max Object Pattern implementation

Tags: java, android, guava

I ended up wrinting the following class:

```
 static class Max {

        private final int value;

        public Max(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Max update(int candidate) {
            if (candidate > value)
                return new Max(candidate);

            return this;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

but somehow I have the feeling that I am reinventing some wheel, but I found no common implementation in my classpath ( guava , android-api )
Is there anything in the above classpath that I am missing or a small lib to do exacltly this?
I am aware of Math.max - but I want the builder pattern here

Comment: Unclear why `Math.max()` is insufficient. You want the builder pattern, and you want someone else to have written it the way you want it? Also, your class only works for `int`(s).

Comment: It only has to work for ints and the code just is more OOP and reads nicer

Comment: Well, if you target `Java-8`, there is [`IntSummaryStatistics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html), otherwise just use your class…